# disconnected dbcontext does not update navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext, navigation-properties

I am writing an API using WebAPI 2.0 and EF6.0 using code first.
So its necessarily a disconnected dbcontext scenario.

My domain is as as below

```
public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email ( get; set; }
    public virtual Nutritionist Nutritionist { get; set; }
}

public class Nutritionist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
}
```

The UI will allow Patient to select a different Nutritionist if she is not happy with current one. So my API needs to support this. I presumed this would be a simple update on the Patient. But following unit test fails.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Changing_Nutritionist_In_Disconnected_Context_Works()
    {
        Patient p;
        Nutritionist n;
        using (var c = new Context())
        {
            // Get a patient where I know p.Nutritionist.Id == 1 in database.
            p = c.Patients.Find(1);

            // Get some other nutritionist
            n = c.Nutritionists.Find(3);
        }
        using (var c = new Context())
        {
            //change patient's email and nutritionist 
            p.Email = "patient@domain.com";
            p.Nutritionist = n;

            c.Patients.Attach(p);
            c.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
            c.SaveChanges();
        }
        using (var c = new Context())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(3,c.Patients.Find(1).Nutritionist.Id);
        }
    }
```

I expected that `SaveChanges()` would save changes to both properties of the patient `p.Email` and `p.Nutritionist`. But in database, only the email is changed and `Nutritionist_Id` field continues to show old value. So for some reason, dbContext is ignoring changes to navigation property `p.Nutritionist`

The SQL profiler shows following UPDATE query fired by EF

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Patients]
SET [Name] = @0, [Email] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)
',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 nvarchar(max) ,@2 int',@0=N'some name',@1=N'patient@domain.com',@2=1
go
```

Wonder what i could be missing out on.

Comment: Well, maybe it's optional but in your `Patient` entity you don't have `public long NutritionistId { get; set; }`. I am not sure if this affects the final behaviour but it doesn't hurt to try adding it.

Comment: Setting `EntityState.Modified` only affects primitive properties, not references. You have to load the `Nutritionist` reference property and then modify it. Or, as said, expose a primitive foreign key property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I could use an explicit property `p.NutritionistId` but I was just trying to be a purist :)

I found out that following code works...

```
cn.Patients.Attach(p);
cn.Nutritionists.Attach(n);
cn.Entry(p).Reference(x => x.Nutritionist).Load();
p.Nutritionist = n;
cn.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified;
cn.SaveChanges();
```

It seems that EF does not automatically **attach** the related entries... `p.Nutritionist` in this case.

Also as [Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) mentioned in the comment above, nor does it load it.

So explicitly loading the `p.Nutritionist` and then changing its value with and attached entity makes EF happy.

I am still wondering why EF would not do all this on its own as it seems a logical programming intent that when I attach a new entity and mark it as `EntityState.Modified`, I want to save the whole of it rather than just scalar properties.